# Can´t convert int.32 to System.Array error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, decimal, data-annotations

I´m using VS 2012 sql management studio, asp.net mvc DataAnnotations and I´m getting an error on the validation of a decimal field:
Can´t convert int.32 to System.Array

```
[Display(Name = "Porcentaje")]
    [MaxLength(21, ErrorMessage = "Máximo 21 caracteres")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requerido")]       
    [RegularExpression(@"^\$?\d+(\.(\d{2}))?$", ErrorMessage = "Número con 
dos decimales")]
    //[Range(0, 9999999999999999.99, ErrorMessage = "Máximo 18 dígitos")]
    public decimal porcentaje { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please provide more details as it is not clear when does that error occur.

Comment: The `MaxLength` and `RegularExpression` attributes don't make sense for a `decimal` as validation is performed after model binding. From the [MaxLengthAttribute docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) "Specifies the maximum length of array or string data allowed in a property."

Comment: OK... y con respecto al error?

Comment: @JhonHernández google translate tells me you're asking about the error. Sounds like  `MaxLength` is trying to coerce `decimal porcentaje` in to an array so it can check it's length but it's not and freaks out. Remove the `MaxLength` and `RegularExpression` attributes - they aren't relevant for a decimal.

Comment: I´m sorry I forgot that I had to speak in english... I´ll try

Comment: there is a Spanish-language Stackoverflow as well if you wish to use that: https://es.stackoverflow.com/ . Anyway, numbers don't have a length. You can't check it like that. You could set a maximum _value_ for the number though.

Comment: No... the error is still coming up